# Remove Spaces in Google Sheets Query using trim

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, trim

I have this query in Google Sheets -

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(B2,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B3,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B4,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B5,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B6,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B7,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B8,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B9,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B10,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B11,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B12,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B13,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B14,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B15,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B16,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B17,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B18,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B19,B1);IMPORTRANGE(B20,B1)},"SELECT Col1,Col17,Col18,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22 WHERE Col1 <> '' AND Col13 <> 1",0)`

Is there a way for me add the TRIM function for everything being retried in column 1 ? I have some names from a form that have a space at the end that gets carriade forward into sheets.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I can't do that because the example has links to other sheets where it is pulling the data from which I can't share.   The query is pulling the same columns from 20 different sheets all consistent data,  Col 1 sometimes has names with a space at the end, sometimes same name no space, so when pivot them it creates 2 entries not 1.

Comment: i added an image, what is returned in collumn A needs to be trimmed as some names have white space

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can do that, but then it convers the numbers in the other columns into text and the subsequent pivot charts won't work, I would need it just to apply to 1 collum

Answer (score 0):

Try pre-trimming only the first column:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IMPORTRANGE(B2, B1)));
    IMPORTRANGE(B3, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B4, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B5, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B6, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B7, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B8, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B9, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B10, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B11, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B12, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B13, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B14, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B15, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B16, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B17, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B18, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B19, B1);
    IMPORTRANGE(B20, B1)
  },
  "SELECT Col1, Col17, Col18, Col4,
          Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8,
          Col9, Col11, Col12, Col13,
          Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22
   WHERE     Col1 <> ''
         AND Col13 <> 1",
  0
)
```